# Retrive a set of documents from array in MongoDB using Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a MongoDB document structure like this:

```
{ 
  "name": "list"
  "config": "default"
  "items": [
    {
      "email": "user1@mail.com"
      "status": true
      "number": 123
    },
    ...
    {
      "email": "user100@mail.com"
      "status": false
      "number": 432
    },
   ]
}
```

Now, how can I retrive multiple subdocuments that much certain criteria. For instance, I want to obtain all documents where ***status = true***. I know that it is possible to use **$elemMatch**, but it returns only the first matching instance and I need **ALL** documents that correspond to the specified condition. Please show how can it be done with Java.

Comment: $elemMatch does not return only the first mathing instance. It returns all the documents that matched with the given criteria. Check docs again. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/

Comment: Yes, indeed I saw that doc, but in Java I cannot figure out how to do it. Also there is this kind of $elemMatch http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/. I am a little confused how to use it so that I could retrive multiple values.

Comment: parvin, could you please show the example in Java of how to use $elemMatch to obtain multiple fields. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in Java as follows.

```
        Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost:27017");
        DB db = mongo.getDB("myDB");
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("myCollection");

        DBObject statusQuery = new BasicDBObject("status", true);
        DBObject elemMatchQuery = new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", statusQuery);

        DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
        fields.put("items", elemMatchQuery);
        fields.put("name", 1);
        fields.put("config", 1);

        DBCursor cur = coll.find(new BasicDBObject(), fields);

        while (cur.hasNext()) {
            DBObject obj = cur.next();
            // Get fields from object
        }
```

Comment: parvin, thanks for your answer. Actually, I used the similar idea to do this. However, the problem is still present I launched your code and got the same issue. Now in my "items" array I have only two docs, one with false status and one with true, when I run the code I got both results! But I only need the one with true. Where can be the problem?

Comment: You want to project your results. I have updated the code above. Check it again.

Comment: Why is filtering data (i.e. elemMatchQuery) joined with projection data and the filtering data (i.e. fields), while the filtering parameter is a blank object (i.e. `new BasicDBObject()` in `coll.find`) !?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all subdocuments from the list `items` in separate  documents, you can `$unwind` the list. I also added filter matching `status` is  `true`:

```
try (MongoClient client = new MongoClient()) {

        MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("myDB");
        MongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = db.getCollection("myColl", BsonDocument.class);

        MongoCursor<BsonDocument> cursor =
                collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(new Document("$unwind", "$items"),
                                                    new Document("$match", new Document("items.status", true)))).iterator();

        try {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                // I think this is what you need
                BsonDocument bsonDocument = cursor.next().getDocument("items");

                // and if you just want emails
                String email = bsonDocument.get("email").asString().getValue();
                System.out.println(email);
            }

        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```